# Filter user by Role cause a infinity recursion

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, jhipster

**Overview**
I'm learning Angular Java and JHipster, and I'm trying to filter the Users by Role but im getting a infinity recursion.

this is my **userRepository.java**

```
@Query(value = "select user from User user inner join user.authorities authorities where authorities.name =:role")
List<User> findByRole(@Param("role") String role);
```

I trying to do a inner join between the user table and the user_authority table, im parsing the role like a String `"ROLE_ADMIN"`

**Upadte**

Found something in the model if i do this `select user.login` instead of `select users` don't get the recursion error, so I think is maybe cause in the model is calling itself several times.

I have a relationship 1:1 with a another entity called extendedUser (for save additional information) and in extendedUser i have another relationship with user called coordinator  so I think the model is calling itself.

This is just a part of the recursion in the console:

```
    2019-03-22 14:08:32.082  WARN 12044 --- [  XNIO-2 task-9] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.ExtendedUser["usuario"]->com.gits.sigem.domain.User["extendedUser"]
```

And this is my **DTO** on extended user when i think I have the problem

```
/**
 * A DTO for the ExtendedUser entity.
 */
public class ExtendedUserDTO extends UserDTO implements Serializable {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtendedUserDTO.class);
    private Long id;

    private String puesto;

    private BigDecimal sueldo;

    private LocalDate fechaIngreso;

    private Long usuarioId;

    //private Long coordinadorId;

    private Set<Area> areas = new HashSet<>();


    private Long coordinadorId;

    private String coordinadorLogin;


    private User coordinador;

    private Set<Desarrollo> desarrollos = new HashSet<>();

    public ExtendedUserDTO(){

    }

    public ExtendedUserDTO(User user){
        super(user);
        this.puesto = user.getExtendedUser().getPuesto();
        this.sueldo = user.getExtendedUser().getSueldo();
        this.fechaIngreso = user.getExtendedUser().getFechaIngreso();
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.usuarioId = user.getId();
        this.coordinadorLogin = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador().getLogin();
        this.coordinadorId = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador().getId();
        this.coordinador = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinador();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getExtendedUser().getAreas());
        this.areas = user.getExtendedUser().getAreas();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getExtendedUser().getDesarrollos());
        this.desarrollos = user.getExtendedUser().getDesarrollos();

    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPuesto() {
        return puesto;
    }

    public void setPuesto(String puesto) {
        this.puesto = puesto;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSueldo() {
        return sueldo;
    }

    public void setSueldo(BigDecimal sueldo) {
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaIngreso() {
        return fechaIngreso;
    }

    public void setFechaIngreso(LocalDate fechaIngreso) {
        this.fechaIngreso = fechaIngreso;
    }

    public Long getUsuarioId() {
        return usuarioId;
    }

    public void setUsuarioId(Long userId) {
        this.usuarioId = userId;
    }

    /* public void setCoordinadorId(Long userId) {
        this.coordinadorId = userId;
    }

    public Long getCoordinadorId() {
        return coordinadorId;
    }*/


    public User getCoordinador() {
        return coordinador;
    }

    public void setCoordinador(User user) {
        this.coordinador = user;
    }


    public Set<Area> getAreas() {
        return areas;
    }

    public void setAreas(Set<Area> areas) {
        this.areas = areas;
    }

    public Set<Desarrollo> getDesarrollos() {
        return desarrollos;
    }

    public void setDesarrollos(Set<Desarrollo> desarrollos) {
        this.desarrollos = desarrollos;
    }

    public Long getCoordinadorId() {
        return coordinadorId;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorId(Long userId) {
        this.coordinadorId = userId;
    }

    public String getCoordinadorLogin() {
        return coordinadorLogin;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorLogin(String userLogin) {
        this.coordinadorLogin = userLogin;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        ExtendedUserDTO extendedUserDTO = (ExtendedUserDTO) o;
        if (extendedUserDTO.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), extendedUserDTO.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExtendedUserDTO{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", puesto='" + getPuesto() + "'" +
            ", sueldo=" + getSueldo() +
            ", fechaIngreso='" + getFechaIngreso() + "'" +
            ", usuario=" + getUsuarioId() +
            ", coordinador='" + getCoordinadorLogin() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- I'm really new on Angular, Java, and Jhipster.
- Please if I missed something important, let me know on the comment
  and I will added to the question.
- Im just trying to get only the ADMIN users so if you have a better
  way I really would like to know

Comment: You didn't post the stack trace of the exception, so we can only make guesses. My guess is that you're trying to serialize users as JSON, and that there is a bidirectional association betwee user and something else. So serializing a user serializes (for example) its authorities, which serializes the authorities user, which serializes its authorities, etc. etc.

Comment: @JBNizet hi I just added the stack trace I think the problem is a another entity I have, someone tell me I have to use ```@jsonignore```

Comment: You have a Usr which references an ExtendedUser, which references a User, etc. etc. And the exception explicitly says "Could not write JSON". So it's just what I suspected (and it's written right there in the exception message). Caredully use annotation to serialize what you actually want to serialize. Or better, IMHO, stop serializing your persistence model. Create DTOs that contain what you want to serialize and nothing else, and are thus designed to represent the response of your API.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you! i just start to learn all this and I trying to do in best way posible, the problem is in the DTO of ExtendedUser, I call user so that way I can see and update booth at the same time, so you think I should make a new DTO just for this?

Comment: I think the persistence model should not be used as the external API responses. They're two related, but different things, each with their own, often contracitory constraints.